# Wait on thread that creates an instance that creates a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

Let me paint my situation:

I have a WCF server which creates a thread. That thread executes an assembly, lets call it `ABC.exe`.
This `ABC.exe` does this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        objClientBase.OnHandshakeCompleted += new EventHandler(objClientBase_OnHandshakeCompleted);
        objClientBase.OnShutdownInitiated += new EventHandler(objClientBase_OnShutdownInitiated);
        objClientBase.Connect();
        objOEEMon = new Main();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

Where `Connect` does:

```
        objClientThread = new Thread(start) { IsBackground = true };
        objClientThread.Start();
```

And `start`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the client program.
    /// </summary>
    private void start()
    {
            //We Open the proxy to let connections happen
            objProxy.Open();
            if (performHandshake())
            {
                IsConnected = true;
                DelayedShutdownBool = false;
                //While connected, the thread keeps the client alive
                while (IsConnected)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    if (DelayedShutdownBool)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        objProxy.Close();
                        objConfiguration = null;
                        IsConnected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

this `ABC.exe` is the client which connects to the server with WCF.

So instead of having the `Sleep(Infinite)` I want to use `manualResetEvent`s (or other thing) so the `Main()` gets notified about the end of the thread that `Connect` makes and end his execution too. But I don't know how the `Main` can get notified, because is calling a function of an instance that creates a thread.

What I don't want is a active wait where there is a `while(condition) sleep`

Comment: Why are you threading at all in that ABC project? The main thread only waits for the other one.

Comment: You have multiple `Sleep()`s. Consider each one a design flaw.

Comment: It is already design like this, I just have to change the sleep.infinite and make it wait until the thread created with the connect finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault...I was passing a new instance of my class instead of the current one, so my callback was done to another instance and so the variables modified were not the correct ones.

Works perfect now.
Thanks for the answers, they helped me think about the sequence to think about where was the error.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use `Task` class instead of explicitly creating the `Thread`

```
 //here instead of creating a Thread, create a Task and return it to the caller
 objClientThread = new Thread(start) { IsBackground = true };
 objClientThread.Start();
```

Then you can do

```
 Task task = objClientBase.Connect();
 task.Wait();
```

Comment: objClientBase.Connect() creates a thread but does not return the thread.
Need to keep threads instead of task sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a manual reset event you would do the following, declare a new reset event:

```
private static ManualResetEvent finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Wait on the event:

```
        //We Open the proxy to let connections happen
        objProxy.Open();
        if (performHandshake())
        {
            IsConnected = true;
            DelayedShutdownBool = false;
            //While connected, the thread keeps the client alive
            finished.WaitOne();
            if (DelayedShutdownBool)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                objProxy.Close();
                objConfiguration = null;
                IsConnected = false;
            }
        }
```

And then in objClientBase_OnShutdownInitiated:

```
finished.Set();
```

Comment: That is not the thread that has to wait. The one that need the WaitOne would be the `Main` one, but then the problem is, how do I do the `Set` inside the instance `objClientBase`?

Comment: First of all you don't need to sleep or wait in the main thread as the process will stay alive as long as there is one thread that is alive.  Secondly you should need to signal the Set from inside ObjClientBase - there's already a nice event that notifies when it's shutting down.

Comment: False, If I dont have it (sleep or wait at the end), my main program reaches the end and dies.
I mean yes I also have a boolean called `IsConnected` which I can check but I dont a while(IsConnected) sleep. I dont want sleeps there.
The problem is I cant access a value of the manual reset event to set it inside the clientbase instance.

Comment: Change the objClientThread so that it is not a Background thread and the process will not exit.

Comment: Is still dying. I neet to put something there that holds the thread.
I have a boolean which knows if its dead or not but I dont want to do an active wait.

Comment: It dies even though IsBackground = false? Do you reach the `while (IsConnected)` line or the `finished.WaitOne();` line?